# Store input field value with select option if product width=22 and select option select product width = inch store like product width = 22 inch

Tags: php

First i send data in post to controller like this

```
[Product_Id] => 11
    [selected_Product_Id] => ASIN
    [Product_Name] => 22
    [Brand_Name] => 33
    [Country_Of_Origin] => India
    [Product_Length] => 44
    [selected_Product_Length] => Angstrom
    [Product_Width] => 55
    [selected_Product_Width] => Angstrom
    [Product_Height] => 66
    [selected_Product_Height] => Angstrom
    [Number_of_Pieces] => 77
    [Included_Components] => 88
    [Assembly_Instruction] => 99
    [Size] => 10
    [Wood_Type] => 20
```

then in back-end to store data i used

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $name = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
        $replace_name = str_replace('_', ' ', $key) ."=".$value. '<br />' ;
        
        echo $replace_name.<br />;

        //if(strpos($name, 'selected') !== false){

            //$select_name = str_replace('selected', '', $name);

            //echo $select_name.'='.$value.'<br />';

            
        //}else{
            //echo $replace_name;
        //}

    
        // if (preg_match('/\b'.$select_name.'\b/', $name)) {
        //      echo $name ;

        //  }

    }
```

**here the data i get**

Product Id=11
selected Product Id=ASIN
Product Name=22
Brand Name=33
Country Of Origin=India
Product Length=44
selected Product Length=Angstrom
Product Width=55
selected Product Width=Angstrom
Product Height=66
selected Product Height=Angstrom
Number of Pieces=77
Included Components=88
Assembly Instruction=99
Size=10
Wood Type=20

**but i want like this**

Product Id=11 ASIN
Product Name=22
Brand Name=33
Country Of Origin=India
Product Length=44 Angstrom
Product Width=55 Angstrom
Product Height=66 Angstrom
Number of Pieces=77
Included Components=88
Assembly Instruction=99
Size=10
Wood Type=20

**sorry for my short explanation i did not know how to explan but if i have one input with select tag i want input name as e.g. product width = 22 + select tag option value which i get in post inch like product width = 22 inch**

**After when i get above data need to covert that data into array like this**

```
array(
    [Product_Id] => 11 ASIN
    [Product_Name] => 22
    [Brand_Name] => 33
    [Country_Of_Origin] => India
    [Product_Length] => 44  Angstrom
    [Product_Width] => 55 Angstrom
    [Product_Height] => 66 Angstrom
    [Number_of_Pieces] => 77
    [Included_Components] => 88
    [Assembly_Instruction] => 99
    [Size] => 10
    [Wood_Type] => 20
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first loop you format your keys and gather "selected_" keys to be processed later (because it must be appended to the end of value)

Then you loop these "selected_" keys and append to existing values.

Finally you print everything out:

```php
<?php

$input = [
    'Product_Id' => 11,
    'selected_Product_Id' => 'ASIN',
    'Product_Name' => 22,
    'Brand_Name' => 33,
    'Country_Of_Origin' => 'India',
    'Product_Length' => 44,
    'selected_Product_Length' => 'Angstrom',
    'Product_Width' => 55,
    'selected_Product_Width' => 'Angstrom',
    'Product_Height' => 66,
    'selected_Product_Height' => 'Angstrom',
    'Number_of_Pieces' => 77,
    'Included_Components' => 88,
    'Assembly_Instruction' => 99,
    'Size' => 10,
    'Wood_Type' => 20,
];

$specialKeys = [];
$formatted = [];

foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'selected_') === 0) {
        $name = str_replace('selected_', '', $key);
        $name = str_replace('_', ' ', $name);
        $specialKeys[$name] = $value;

        continue;
    }

    $name = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
    $replaceName = str_replace('_', ' ', $key) ."=".$value. '<br />' ;
        
    $formatted[$name] = $value;
}

foreach ($specialKeys as $key => $value) {
    $formatted[$key] .= " {$value}";   
}

foreach ($formatted as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$key} => $value" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51e29d967b2343f55caa68ea107d74991f7aa469)